# How do I transfer coins from Coinbase to a UK bank account?

Tags: ether, coinbase

**What I have**

- Ethereum
- Litecoin

**Which Exchange I'm using**

- Coinbase

**My Issue**

- I cannot get my funds back to my UK bank account

**Questions**

1. How do I do this? I've a bunch of things online, all of which tend to be terrible support requests to set up a SEPA and still no luck
2. Is it possible to transfer my Ethereum and Litecoin to another exchange?
3. Are there any UK exchanges that would allow me to transfer my coins over as well as transfer back to my UK bank account?

Coinbase have an incredible ability not to respond to peoples forum discussions, emails, or twitter posts or provide any form of update.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Reply to below Comment: "Thanks Edmund. I'm trying to avoid the SEPA has Coinbase have been getting some bad feedback recently. I can't risk waiting for months for them to activate / authorise the sepa. I'll try one of the exchanges you mentioned to see if I can transfer stuff over. I appreciate your time on this :) – Tron Aug 9 at 12:48".
Did this worked for you Tron. Please let me know as I am facing same issue and also new to this.
Thanks.

Comment: No. I moved everything out of coinbase. Their support is utter nonsense. Look at something like https://uphold.com/. I transferred everything there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13647)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks - Who is that response aimed at precisely?

Comment: @Tron Hi there. That's an auto-review comment that was added when I reviewed Abhijit's post (via the moderator review queue). He added an answer for what should have been a comment, and these are generally picked up by the moderators. They're then converted to comments manually, and any "comment flags" - i.e. my comment - are removed. I'm unsure why that hasn't happened in this case. So it was aimed at Abhijit, who, to be fair, and as is usual in these cases, doesn't yet have enough reputation to leave comments.

Comment: Can I withdraw ETH from Coinbase to a UK bank account?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29098)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to transfer GBP using any exchange that supports SEPA. This should include Coinbase, but if that's not working for you then you may want to try Kraken or BitStamp. You should be able to withdraw your digital currency from Coinbase to either your own wallet or your deposit address at another exchange.

Note that these exchanges may have identity verification requirements that have to be satisfied before they will allow you to withdraw large sums, or at all. You may need to complete identity verification steps to withdraw digital currency from Coinbase, and also to withdraw GBP from either Coinbase or whatever exchange that you try using instead.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response Edmund. Coinbase support Sepa, but according to recent forms it isn't working for a great deal of people and Coinbase aren't responding to their emails, tweets for the last 4 months. I'd rather not invest any further money into that company.

I've very new to this. If I set up an account on Kraken or BitStamp (and go through the usual identity checks), how easy is it to transfer from Coinbase to them? What's the process?

Comment: I imagine Coinbase have had a support backlog related to the recent fork, so it might be worth just waiting a bit. However, assuming you've done whatever identity verification you need at Coinbase, transferring digital currency out should just be a matter of getting a deposit address from the other exchange (this will be your personal address from your deposit screen, don't just use any other address you might find) and sending to that from the Coinbase withdraw screen.

Comment: BTW, I may be stating the obvious but to withdraw GBP to a UK account you must first have GBP, which implies first selling the coins you want to withdraw for GBP. You might like to try selling a test amount on Coinbase then seeing if you can work out how to navigate the screen to initiate the SEPA transfer.

Comment: Thanks Edmund. I'm trying to avoid the SEPA has Coinbase have been getting some bad feedback recently. I can't risk waiting for months for them to activate / authorise the sepa. I'll try one of the exchanges you mentioned to see if I can transfer stuff over. I appreciate your time on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I've just managed to withdraw everything from coinbase using uphold.com they are brilliant and really fast, you have no choice but to send your bitcoin/litecoin to address you receive via uphold.com, this will mean coinbase still make money off you but it also means you won't be sick of waiting to withdraw ur own funds.